# Render a checkbox and check it based on the existence of a value from a dataset to another dataset

Tags: javascript, vue.js, handlebars.js

My idea is to checked whether a value exists  from a dataset to another dataset. In this case I would like to use the `id` property.

I'm try handlebars.js , But the following is invalid.

spot_categories array

```
{spot_categories:[{category:1},{category:2},{category:3},{category:4},{category:5},{category:6}]}
```

data array

```
{data:[{spot_category_id:1},{spot_category_id:3}]}
```

vue.js code

```
<!-- if have var -->
{{# var ok = false}}
<!-- one for -->
<li v-for="(category,j) in spot_categories">
  <label>
        <!-- two for -->
        <template v-for="(val, l) in data">
           <!-- if -->
           <template v-if="val.spot_category_id == category.id">
              {{ ok = true }}
           </template>
        </template>
        <!-- if ok = true , show value -->
        <input :value="category.id" :checked="ok">
  </label>
</li>
```

How can I do?  Please help me. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at looping once only in your template using your `spot_categories` dataset and then calling a method to evaluate if its id exists on another dataset. I use `v-if` and `v-else` to decide which checkbox element to render. Then I implement `array.some()` on my evaluation method which is the most fitting in this scenario (you can use a manual for loop but it's too lengthy and generally not recommended if you want a clean-looking code).

```js
new Vue({
    el: categoryContainers,
    data: {
      spot_categories: [
        {id: 1},
        {id: 2}
      ],
      data: [
        {spot_category_id: 1},
        {spot_category_id: 3}
      ]
    },
    methods: {
      checkIfExists: function(item1){
         return this.data.some(function(val){ return val.spot_category_id == item1.id });
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="categoryContainers">
   <ul>
      <li v-for="(category,j) in spot_categories">
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" v-if="checkIfExists(category)" :value="category.id" checked>
            <input type="checkbox" v-else :value="category.id">
            {{ 'Category ID ' + category.id }}
       </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```